# Detect the sim being called to on Android

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I am trying to detect the sim/number begin called to in case of dual sim. I am using a broadcast receiver with `<action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />`. I am able to get the number from which the call came, however, I want to know which number/sim, the call was made to.

I am using Android 27 for my application. **How can I fetch the details of the sim/number being called to?**

Thanks.

Comment: the person who downvoted have some courtesy to put the reason for the same.

Comment: I don't have any advice regarding this question but I upvoted this to help you :)